# Trying to print first twenty lines of PSL file

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have this code that reads a PSL file. I've pasted the whole thing below for clarity, but what I'm really focusing on right now is the readPSLpairs method (it's at the very bottom). For now, I'm just trying to have that method print the first twenty lines of the psl file, but for some reason it's not... I didn't receive an error message or anything - but the program is just blank. What am I missing? Thanks.

```
import sys
class PSLreader :
    '''
    Class to provide reading of a file containing psl alignments
    formatted sequences:
    object instantiation:
    myPSLreader = PSLreader(<file name>):

    object attributes:
    fname: the initial file name

    methods:
    readPSL() : reads psl file, yielding those alignments that are within the first or last
                1000 nt

    readPSLpairs() : yields psl pairs that support a circular hypothesis 

    Author: David Bernick
    Date: May 12, 2013
    '''

    def __init__ (self, fname='EEV14-Cb.filtered.psl'):
        '''contructor: saves attribute fname '''

        self.fname = fname

    def doOpen (self):
        if self.fname is '':
            return sys.stdin
        else:
            return open(self.fname)

    def readPSL (self):
        '''
        using filename given in init, returns each filtered psl records
        that contain alignments that are within the terminal 1000nt of
        the target. Incomplete psl records are discarded.
        If filename was not provided, stdin is used.

        This method selects for alignments that could may be part of a
        circle.

        Illumina pairs aligned to the top strand would have read1(+) and read2(-).
        For the bottoms trand, read1(-) and read2(+).

        For potential circularity,
        these are the conditions that can support circularity:
        read1(+) near the 3' terminus
        read1(-) near the 5' terminus
        read2(-) near the 5' terminus
        read2(+) near the 3' terminus

        so...
        any read(+) near the 3', or
        any read(-) near the 5'

        '''

        nearEnd = 1000   # this constant determines "near the end"
        with self.doOpen() as fileH:

            for line in fileH:
                pslList = line.split()
                if len(pslList) < 17:
                    continue
                tSize = int(pslList[14])
                tStart = int(pslList[15])
                strand = str(pslList[8])

                if strand.startswith('+') and (tSize - tStart > nearEnd):
                    continue
                elif strand.startswith('-') and (tStart > nearEnd):
                    continue

                yield line

    def readPSLpairs (self):
        i = 0
        for psl in self.readPSL():
            if i>20:
                print(psl.split())
                i+=1
```

EDIT: So I tried to refer back to main like this:

```
def main():
    new_psl = PSLreader(fname)
    new_psl.readPSLpairs()#creating class objects
    new_psl.output()

main()
```

but this still does not make the code work... the error states, "NameError: global name 'fname' is not defined"

Comment: what do you get when you do `print(fname)`? If you get nothing then assign `fname = 'EEV14-Cb.filtered.psl'` or simply omit this option as it is already the default option of your class definition

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the check `i>20` in your `readPSLpairs` function means that the program will only print lines *after* the 20th line. If your file is only 20 lines long (or has less than 20 lines that satisfy the constraints in `readPSL`, that could explain your problem. I would check how many lines make it through the checks in `readPSL` (the ones of the form `if condition: continue`); try putting some print statements in `readPSL`.

Also, if this is your entire program, you don't have any `main` method which actually runs this; ensure that your code is actually running something!

Comment: how would the main method look like? I'm always making mistakes with syntax

Comment: *(Note: The name "main" isn't special)* Best practice is to define a top-level function called `main`, which in your case would create an instance of `PSLReader`, run `readPSLpairs`. Then you would add the check `if __name__ == '__main__': main()` after defining that function, so that you can invoke this with `python filename.py`. However, if you're just running this from the interpretive shell, then the `main` stuff doesn't matter.